# RxSearchView not supporting androidx SearchView?

Tags: android, rx-java2, searchview, androidx

I've migrated my project to androidx. When i use `RxSearchView` it results in an error

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView).
```

Type mismatch.
Required:
**android.widget.SearchView**

Found:

**androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView**

Comment: Well it sounds like you are talking to the support library version of SearchView, while RxSearchView is looking for the non-support library version.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I understood that, is there androidx dependent rxcomponents available?

Comment: Have you looked here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/issues/450 You should generally begin with the Github repo of the code you intend to use. The issue was fixed & closed. Try using the Jetifier for AndroidX, see [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) and [Jetifier Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/jetifier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing this problem recently and was able to fix it by using this explicit dependency: `implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding3:rxbinding-appcompat:3.0.0-alpha2'`.
You can find this dependency and some other ones at [Github RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding).
I hope I was not too late and I hope this helps!

**Edit**
I know I responded this not long ago but something messed up the library. `3.0.0-alpha` is no longer the latest release and has been replaced with version `3.0.0` of which I no longer find `RxSearchView` anywhere, not even on the `alpha` version.

**Edit 2**
Since I never found `RxSearchView` again, I had to implement an `OnQueryTextListener` myself, following a pretty cool tutorial I found [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/implementing-search-on-type-in-android-with-coroutines-ab117c8f13a4). It uses `Kotlin`'s new `coroutines` and works as fine as `RxSearchview`.

Answer (score 1):

If you update your dependency to the rxbinding3, version 3.0.0 by adding the following line in your app's `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding3:rxbinding-appcompat:3.0.0'
```

Then you should be fine by simply using the new API adapted to the Kotlin style:

Replace your code where it has

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChangeEvents(searchView)
```

to

```
searchView.queryTextChangeEvents()
```

Also keep in mind that the return value typed as `SearchViewQueryTextEvent` uses property access, so things like `it.queryText()` should be changed to `it.queryText`.